# ViewPager Is Not Scrolling Smoothly

Tags: android, android-viewpager

i implemented a viewpager in my activity that on scroll, loads a set of data to an adapter and display them in a list view. everything is working fine, but i cant seem to find out how to make it more efficient because when scrolling, the view freezes but for example in the GMAIL app when scrolling between Emails the scrolling is so smooth.

Below is the code i am using:

Activity:

in oncreate

```
pageradapter adapter2 = new pageradapter(this, ArrayOfItems);   //ArrayOfItems is an Array containing the data that will be displayed
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.mypanelpager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter2);
pagechangelistener pageListener = new pagechangelistener();
        myPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageListener);
```

pageradapter:

```
public pageradapter(Activity act, ArrayList <List<Item>>Arrayitems) {
    this.Arrayitems = Arrayitems;
    activity = act;
}

public int getCount() {
    return Arrayitems.size();
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    List<Item> item = Arrayitems.get(position);
    ListView view = new ListView(activity);
    taskdetailsarrayadaptertest adapter = new taskdetailsarrayadaptertest(activity, item);
    view.setAdapter(adapter);
    view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}
```

pagechangelistener:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position)
{
    currentPage = position;
    int positionTemp = position + 1;
}

public final int getCurrentPage() {
    return currentPage;
}
```

Comment: try to use https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/VelocityViewPager

Comment: thank you for your fast response but do you think my code is efficient ?

Comment: are you properly handling loading data in listview, I mean doing it in background ? Because you code looks OK and must not lag unless listview itself has lag in it.

Comment: Your code looks fine.

Comment: the data is being loaded when in oncreate (at once). Do u mean that i should load the data dynamically while scrolling?

Comment: pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit);
use it. it make when pager adapter make views and save in memory limit view count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to use holders like this.

in your ViewPager:

```
class Holder{
    ListView listView;
    Adapter adapter;
}

private ArrayList<Holder> mHolders;

//init holders

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
    Holder holder = mHolders.get(position);
    holder.listView.setAdapter(holder.adapter);
    collection.addView(holder.listView);
    return holder.listView;
}
```

Second try async loading data in listview

Comment: should i load the asynctask in instantiateItem method? because i tried that and then i get a nullpointer exception because the return statement is being executed before the async task finishes.

Comment: You should use asynctask in adapter of listview to loading data in listview

Answer (score 0):

set myPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

Comment: this helped but did not eliminate the issue

Comment: Do you load image in ViewPager?